# Is 1h 40 min enough to connect from International to Qantas Domestic at Melbourne Airport (MEL) on a single ticket?

Tags: short-connections, qantas, mel

I'm an international traveller. I'm travelling to Canberra via Melbourne on a single ticket. My flight has a transit at Melbourne (MEL) Airport. From Melbourne, it is Qantas Airways flight which I have to take to Canberra.

I do have Australian visitor VISA. So transit isn't a problem.

But my connection time is **1hour and 40 minutes**. So I'm worried whether I have to collect my luggages and re check them to Qantas Airways? Whether I have to go through Australian immigration, before I go to the connection flight which I have to do within 1hour and 40 minutes of time.

Since I'm coming from an international flight (which will be landing at terminal 2) I have to go to terminal 1 to get the other flight. So I doubt whether 1hour and 40 minutes connection time would be enough?

Comment: Is this connection on a single booking or multiple bookings?

Comment: Also, what passport will you be using? This will determine if you can use the immigration Autogates, which are much faster than regular immigration.

Comment: @k2moo4, I booked directly from my country to Canberra. So it is in a single booking.

Comment: Whatever you do ........ don't carry any foodstuffs!

Answer (score 5):

1:40 for an international to domestical connection at MEL is **doable but risky**, since Immigration and Customs can have long queues at times.  However, all terminals are directly next to each other at MEL and you can easily walk between them, so once through the transfer will be quick and easy.  There's also a special bag drop area for Qantas connections after Customs, so if you already have your boarding pass you don't need to queue to check in again.

*If* your flights are on a single ticket, you'll be fine: even if you miss the connection, you'll just be put on the next flight, which Qantas operates between Melbourne and Canberra hourly.  If not, though, I would advise you to rebook to add more buffer.

Comment: My flights are on a single ticket. I purchased directly from my country to Canberra and vice versa. Melbourne is there as a transit. Rebooking would add an extra cost, that's why I raised this question.

Comment: @Mad, if "they" make you miss the connection, they'll just put you on the next shuttle to Canberra (one hour later).  That's the theory.

Comment: What is the minimum connection time at Melbourne for this case?

Comment: @gparyani IIRC 90 min, although I can't find a reference.  That said, since Qantas sold OP the connection, it's by definition legal.